# Инициализация объекта класса при помощи возвращаемого значения из функции

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
 
class Something
{
    
public:

    Something()
    {
        std::cout << "bye" << std::endl;
    }
    
    Something(const Something& a)
    {
        std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
    }
};
 
Something boo() 
{
    Something x;
    std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
    return x;
}
 
int main()
{
    Something y = boo();
    return 0;
}
```

Вопрос: как инициализируется `y`? Если бы использовался конструктор по умолчанию то программа выводила бы `bye 1 bye`, если конструктор копирования то `bye 1 hello`, но результат выполнения `bye 1`

Comment: Правильно. Создается один объект с вызовом конструктора по-умолчанию.

Comment: Почему 1 ? первый это `x` в функции `boo()`, а второй `y` в функции `main()`

Comment: В современных стандартах даже при отсутствии оптимизации навязывается правило возвращать объект без копии.

Comment: Переменные `x` и `y` (а также возвращаемое значение функции) обращаются к одному и тому же объекту. Это называется Return Value Optimization.

Comment: "Оптимизация возвращаемого значения является обязательной и больше не рассматривается как copy elision. (начиная с C++17)" https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Comment: @AlexGlebe в приведённом коде нет обязательной оптимизации, т.к. у возвращаемой переменной есть имя. А значит, это уже NRVO, а не RVO.